# Is there a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, real-numbers, harmonic-numbers

Is there a formula for

$$\sum _{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i} \,?$$

Any help would be great

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: Thanks Alot!!!!

Comment: It is known that $\sum_{n\le x}n^{-1} = \log x+\gamma+O(1/x)$, where $\gamma$ is Euler-Mascheroni constant.